# Action creators fire differently in Redux, how to deal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here is my code:

```
const onHandleAction = (e, action) => {
        // props.resetPage()
        switch (action) {
            case 'set':
                onChangeSet(e)
                break;
            case 'class':
                onChangeClass(e)
                break;
            case 'manaCost':
                onChangeManaCost(e)
                break;
            case 'search':
                onHandleSearch()
                break;
        }
    }

    const onChangeSet = e => {
        props.resetPage()
        if (e.target.value === 'Arena') {
            props.setGameMode(e.target.value);
        } else {
            props.setActualSet(e.target.value);
        }
    };

    const onChangeClass = e => {
        props.resetPage()
        const classValue =
            e.target.value === 'All Classes' ? 'all' : e.target.value;
        props.setClass(classValue);
    };

    const onChangeManaCost = e => { 
        props.resetPage()
        if (props.manaCost.every(m => m !== e.target.value)) {
            props.setManaCost(e.target.value)
        } else {
            props.removeManaCost(e.target.value)
        }
    };
```

As you may notice the line

```
props.resetPage()
```

is repeated 3 times. I've tried to put it in my onHandleAction, so it would fire up before any of those actions but it doesn't work. If I leave the code as it is everything works fine. How to reduce this line of code not to repeat it too many times?

Comment: What does `resetPage` do?

Comment: it doesn't makes anything that would trigger this component to rerender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `props.resetPage();` inside `onHandleAction` should work. Another option is to make a wrapper function that would call `reset` prop and take the action as a callback together with other arguments. An added benefit of this approach is that you can choose which actions to reset page for:

```
const actionWithReset = (action, ...args) => {
  props.resetPage();
  action(args);
}


const onHandleAction = (e, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case 'set':
      actionWithReset(onChangeSet, e)
      break;
    case 'class':
      actionWithReset(onChangeClass, e)
      break;
    case 'manaCost':
      actionWithReset(onChangeManaCost, e)
      break;
    case 'search':
      onHandleSearch()
      break;
  }
}
```